# mysql, php, how to get a count of users?

Tags: php, mysql

i have  a table like this:

```
user  | session
test1 | 11
test1 | 11
test1 | 11
test1 | 21
test1 | 21
test2 | 2
test2 | 2
test3 | 3
test3 | 3
test3 | 32
test3 | 32
```

i would like to get back that `user 1 has 2 sessions`, `user 2 has 1 sessions`, `user 3 has 2 sessions`
bassically how many the same sessions a user has?

i've tryed `$sql4 = SELECT user, session , count(*)  FROM`table`group by user, session`

and i get the distinct sessions but not the count

any ideas?
thanks

edit:

if i use `SELECT user, count(*) FROM users GROUP BY user` i get `test 1 = 5`. it give's me the total nr or sessions instead of total nr of sessions that are the same. in this case `2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user, count(DISTINCT session) FROM users GROUP BY user
```

`DISTINCT` used to calc only unique sessions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the overall number of person online you just need to count the number of user regardless of the session

```
$sql4 = SELECT COUNT(*) from (
        SELECT  distinct(user)
        FROM table) as innerquery
```

This will group all by user what ever the session.
The result will be a simple integer.

If you need to count the amount of session of each user and do not want to have a count for each session you need to remove the duplicate with a Distinct keyword.

```
$sql4 = SELECT user, count(distinct(session)) 
        FROM table 
        GROUP by user
```

The result will be a list of user-># of session